# FPGA to DMA to RDMA

Tags: fpga, dma

I am trying to send data generated from my FPGA card out to an IB device. I want the latency to be as low as possible, so I am thinking this may be the data path.

FPGA --> DMA via scatter/gather DMA into Memory Buffer --> RDMA into a ConnectX-6 card --> IB cable --> my other device.

With this potential solution, I have a bunch of unknowns that I cant seem to find on the internet and was hoping someone could assist:

1. Is this possible/viable? I have never worked with DMA and RDMA and want to make sure it can work before purchasing. I fear it may be a one or the other situation and you can't do both or doing both will cause latency somehow or lost data.
2. Ideally, I want it to reach the other devices CPU (I just want it to avoid the Host device's CPU), but it seems like RDMA makes it avoid both CPUs? Would it then just be DMA to my ConnectX card? I've been searching the datasheets/manuals/firmware/support to see if the ConnectX cards can support DMA, but it doesn't seem to be possible? They just support RDMA (which is a subset of DMA.)

Any information/guidance would be appreciated. If I am in the wrong group, let me know. I wasn't sure if it belonged here or in the stack overflow one (there seemed to be more DMA/RDMA questions there, but they recommended I post it here too)

Comment: What lane speed are you trying to achieve? 28Gbps CML or 50Gbps like Nvidia has achieved  with the MELLANOX CONNECTX-6 VPI?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 about 50 Gbps but potentially more for growth. I imagine I can achieve up to 100 Gbps since the Nvidia ConnectX card allows FDR?

Answer (score 0):

For CONNECT-X type speeds up to 50Gbps/lane at present, RDMA must be used with non+volatile(UPS) DDR hybrid NDRAM to achieve lowest latency.

(Snip)

. RDMA also facilitates a faster data transfer rate and low-latency networking. It can be implemented for networking and storage applications.

How RDMA works

RDMA enables more direct data movement in and out of a server by implementing a transport protocol in the network interface card (NIC) hardware. The technology supports a feature called zero-copy networking that makes it possible to read data directly from the main memory of one computer and write that data directly to the main memory of another computer.

Consult with vendors of this technology with registration.

Ref. https://www.mellanox.com/files/doc-2020/pb-connectx-6-vpi-card.pdf

Comment: Its 50 Gbps/lane, and since theres two ports, thats 100 Gbps right?
Thanks, so if it has to be non-volatile memory, would I need a NVMe memory storage device?
So would I DMA from my FPGA into the PCIe NVMe card and then with it in a block of memory, RDMA it from memory to my other device? Do I need that PCIe NVMe middle man?

Comment: CML ideal is 27 GHz but if using DDR maybe 50 GHz and RDMA is basically dual port DMA memory with NVME3 to/from PCIe etc.  Dual Layer stripline in low loss tangent substrate and perfect short length matching for minimal skew.

Comment: So I'm new to engineering so a lot of this is going over my head. CML? Are you referring to current mode logic? I thought IB and FDR were for 50 Gbps?
So big picture, I want to send data from one device to another with low latency. The ConnectX card appears to only support RDMA so I imagine I would have to DMA data into my memory buffer and then RDMA it to the other device?

Comment: Yes to CML, it’s the fastest logic.  Using NVMe over Fabric (NVMe-oF) protocol , they all use  RDMA connectivity to remotely access NVMe storage devices efficiently, while keeping the end-to-end NVMe model at lowest latency. You will have to read the NVMeoF specs. I’m too busy.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to consider. First, I'm not an expert on RDMA. But I think there are a few options for your setup. One option could be to use the Xilinx RDMA IP core, which means the FPGA can directly communicate via RDMA without a host system. However, I'm not sure if that supports IB or only Ethernet (RoCE). Another option is what you describe, bouncing the data through a buffer in host memory. Another option to consider is using P2P DMA and having the Mellanox NIC DMA it directly off of the FPGA. In this case, you would expose the data via one of the BARs, set up such that it can respond to large read requests. In all of these cases you'll need software to coordinate things, and unfortunately that's the part I'm less familiar with. The thing with RDMA is it doesn't completely bypass the host CPU, it only bypasses it as far as the actual transfer is concerned. My understanding is that the target device has to set up the transfer, then it has to provide the corresponding key to the other device, and then it is informed when the transfer is complete. It's not like you can use RDMA to arbitrarily write to the target device's memory (that would be very dangerous), it has to be done within defined buffers and so on.

Comment: 1. Is the Xilina RDMA IP Core this (https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/ernic/v3_0/pg332-ernic.pdf)? That sounds like a viable solution, but I would like to know more. I believe RoCE could work as long as the latency is low
2. re: P2P DMA, The documentation mentions that they have to be the same PCI bridge (even for PCIe), does that mean on the same switch? I plan on using the HDB8259 and it seems like they'd be on the same switch.
3. re: RDMA, I imagine informing transfer complete is very low latency which is why I was leaning towards that solution.